# select every row in one table and related rows from another

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables, that I made second one `Table B` from first one `Table A` because first table had 52 columns for every book and I did not need them all and from other hand, more than 100000 rows was unusable.

I have 12 columns for every book in table `B`.

table A contains some more information about books, like, `published city`, `cover kind` , **etc...**

Now, I need to have another field in second table ---> `Table B` or in a new one.

This is my logic :

for each `isbn` in table `B`, I need to fetch a column named `city`.

May be like this :

```
foreach isbn in table B,
         fetch `city`, `weight`, `price` from table A
```

I tried this query :

```
select `isbn`, `weight`, `city`  from `database1`.`table1` WHERE 
       (SELECT `isbn` from `database2`.`table2`);
```

but it seems it's not a right way.
Would you please help me to find right way to do this using SQL???

***Thanks in Advance***

Comment: You need to learn about `join`.

Comment: these tables don't have relationship... The engine is MyISAM... I made second table using `concat` and some other sql commands. And I do not want to use InnoDB because mysql version is old and I need fullText search

Comment: . . It would seem that `isbn` is a common key in the two tables.

Answer (score 1):

You could simply join the two tables:

```
SELECT t1.isbn, t1.weight, t1.city 
 FROM table1 t1 
 JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.isbn = t2.isbn;
```